# How to config the log file dir with logback?

Tags: logback

My environments:

ubuntu 18.04

openjdk 8

tomcat 8.5.50

logback 1.2.3

I put my logback.xml in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes, the file like:

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">

        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger - %msg%n</Pattern>

    </layout>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">

    <file>/home/mc/shopping.log</file>

    <append>true</append>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">

        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger - %msg%n</Pattern>

    </layout>

</appender>

<root level="info">

    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

</root>

</configuration>
```

When I start tomcat by bin/startup.sh, I can not find the file shopping.log in /home/mc.

What is my wrong please?

Comment: have you tried to provide the logback configuration file as a java argument like the following ```-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml``` ?

Comment: @NAIT I do not put the -D args. Strange, I put the same war in windows D:/tomcat, the file shopping.log is there(it create a dir D:/home/mc). But why not ubuntu.